# Python read API with json

Tags: python, json, colors

**2020 EDIT**: The API is broken and you can no longer use it.

How would I use a JSON api to get a random colour and put it into a variable.
For now I have tried the following code

The API returns:

```
{"colors": [], "schemes": [{"timestamp": 1463921041, "colors": ["3f1401", "481f00", "876746", "e6e6e6"], "id": "17375", "tags": [{"id": "13311", "name": "what"}]}], "matching_schemes": ["17375"], "schemes_history": {"17375": [{"d_count": 0, "id": "13311", "a_count": 1, "name": "what"}]}, "success": true, "colors_history": {}, "messages": []}
```

and I wish to put name into a variable.

```py
import requests
from json import *
def getcolor():
   colrjson = requests.get("http://www.colr.org/json/scheme/random")
   thing = colrjson.text
   aaa = loads(thing)
   print(aaa["name"])
getcolor()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
=================== RESTART: /home/pi/Desktop/test/main.py ===================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/test/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    getcolor()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/test/main.py", line 8, in getcolor
    print(aaa["name"])
KeyError: 'name'
>>>
```

Comment: I think that `json.loads` return an array. Maybe you can try `print(aaa[0])`

Comment: @DorianB I tried it and got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/test/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    getcolor()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/test/main.py", line 8, in getcolor
    print(aaa[0])
KeyError: 0

Comment: If `aaa` contains your JSON, you should get the name with `name = aaa["schemes"][0]["tags"][0]["name"]`

Comment: Thank you! Post it as an answer and i will upvote :)

Comment: Please update you question with the new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key name is inside not in the first level of your JSON so to access it you have to write : `name = aaa["schemes"][0]["tags"][0]["name"]` because "schemes" key and "tags" key return arrays.

Comment: I upvoted, but i don't have enough reputation for it to be public. :(

Comment: Don't worry but if that solved your problem you can flag it as "answer" :)

Answer (score 1):

If I do

```
import requests
print(requests.get("http://www.colr.org/json/scheme/random/1").text)
```

I get

```
'{"colors": [], "schemes": [], "schemes_history": {}, "success": true, "colors_history": {}, "messages": [], "new_scheme_id": "-1"}\n'
```

So clearly there is no "name" key in the dictionary. That's why you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the original url provided into my browser and it yielded an empty json, with no real content: I have adjusted your function as follows:

```
import requests
from json import *

def getcolor():
    colrjson = requests.get("http://www.colr.org/json/scheme/random").content
    json_file = loads(colrjson)
    print(json_file["schemes"][0]["tags"][0]["name"])
getcolor()
```

Here the "colrjson" takes the **content** of the json file, which is then assigned to variable "json_file" = loads(colrjson). The "loads" method from the json library takes file contents as a string so you are left with the dictionary which you can then traverse using keys and the indices of the inner lists as you provided.

I got the value as: "aurora"

Comment: My code used a URL that doesn't work, i have updated the code with a working url.

Comment: I just made an edit to the code above including the url, hope it helped :)

Comment: It is also advised to specify the content attribute when reading the json file as you ensure that you are reading the body of the content from when you use a http get request